# Possibilities to place n persons on a round table with $2n$ chairs so that there is at least one free chair between each $2$ persons

Tags: combinatorics

How many possibilities are there to place **n persons** on a round table with $2n$ chairs, so that there is at least one free chair between each $2$ persons?

Assuming we have $n = 10$ persons that want to sit there. So we have $n = 20$ chairs. The first person has $20$ choices. After the first person is placed onto his seat, we have $17$ choices, because the seats next to the first person can't be chosen...

So can I say the number of possibilities is $$\sum_{n=0}^n n*(n-3)$$

Or is that totally false?

And how many possibilities are there to place $n$ persons on a round table with **2n+1** chairs, so that there is at least one free chair between each $2$ persons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2n$ chairs.

There are $2$ choices for the chairs that will be possessed by persons.

After that choice there are $n!$ possible arrangements for the persons, so there are $2\cdot n!$ possibilities.

---

$2n+1$ chairs.

There will be exactly $2$ consecutive chairs that will not be possessed and selecting them comes to the same as selecting the chairs that will be possessed. This gives $2n+1$ choices.

After that choice there are $n!$ possible arrangements for the persons, so there are $(2n+1)\cdot n!$ possibilities.

Comment: "possessed" Halloween, eh?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Oeps, my English. Anything wrong with "possessed"? Any link with Halloween?

Comment: Nothing wrong, except that it appears to be a link.

Comment: @drhab, "possessed" as a (past tense) verb means "occupied." As an adjective, it means "controlled by an indwelling demon," as in *The Exorcist*. Hence the reference to Halloween.

Comment: @BarryCipra I see. In Dutch language we have "bezet" for the first (harmless) meaning and "bezeten" for the second.

Comment: @drhab, is there a Dutch translation of Dostoevsky's novel *The Possessed*?

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, there is: "De bezetenen". Actually a nomen substantivum pluralis. I haven't read it (yet).